# Rate widget not working in views

Tags: views, 7, rating, javascript

I have an image gallery which I've made using views and each image has a yes/no rate widget. When the image is clicked a popup box is shown with the image in it which I have made using colorbox. I have also added the yes/no rate widget in the pop up box. The problem is that the rate widget is not working in the gallery but it works inside the popup box. How can I make it work in both the places?

This is strange, but when I click on the rate widget in the popup box for a certain image, it starts working in the gallery as well but only for that image.

This is what my views looks like. Only the `(Votes)Votes:Value` appearing first is working first and then after clicking that the other one works for that particular content.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you used the "Votes: Value" twice, use it once, "Exclude it from display" and render it using tokens as many time as you want and you must be good to go.